# Get ANY element from a list

Tags: java, eclipse, list

I feel like this should be a duplicate because I think it would have already been asked, but I can't find the answer.

I have a list:

```
private List<myObj> myObjList;
```

I want to get ANY element in this list (I don't know if the list is empty or not).

I don't care which element, I just want a single `myObj` returned, such as:

```
myObj o = new myObj;
o = getAnyFromList(myOjbList);
```

What's the best and/or most efficient way to do this?

**EDIT**

To further clarify, I think what I want in Java is something like .NET's First function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Forget about the best way. First try to find *A Way*. Have you looked onto the APIs?

Comment: @RohitJain As far as "A Way", I am essentially already doing what Morko Topolnik's answer is suggesting.  I was hoping Java had some built in function that does the empty check for me.  I will go with Marko's answer for now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest and most efficient way is to return the first element.

```
return myObjList.isEmpty()? null : myObjList.get(0);
```

If you want to replicate .NET's function, then the solution is even simpler.

```
return myObjList.get(0);
```

which will throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the list is empty, just like .NET's version.

Comment: Thanks Marko, this seems to be the best solution. I will accept as soon as I am able.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myObj o = new myObj;

if(null != myOjbList && myOjbList.size() > 0)
    o = myOjbList.get(0);
```